# Trying to add a user inputted variable to end of file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, variables, awk, sed

Using Ubuntu.

Currently I'm trying to add a user inputted variable to the end of a file.
In short, this allows me to use a BASH script to automate adding VSFTPD users.

Currently I have used awk & sed.
I don't have the sed but here is my awk that I currently have together.

```
awk '{$centre_name}' /etc/vsftpd-users
```

Comment: Just use `>>` to append, e.g., `echo $var >> /some/file`?

Comment: I ended up using this @Robert and this worked!

Answer (score 0):

**GNU AWK solution**
You might use `-v` to ram variable into GNU `AWK`, I would do it following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
1
2
3
```

then

```
var1="four"
awk -v var=${var1} '{print}END{print var}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
1
2
3
four
```

Explanation: I use `-v` to set awk's variable `var` value to value of shell's variable `var1` then each line of file I just `print` as-is, after processing is done I do `print` value of `var`.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

**GNU sed** solution You might use `$` to target last line and use command `a` for append line of text as follows, for `file.txt` shown earlier

```
var1="four"
sed "$ a ${var1}" file.txt
```

gives same output as above

*(tested in GNU sed 4.5)*

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks for a great explanation. Is it possible to not print the entire file.txt after script ran?

Edit: Spoke too soon, it displayed the file as if it added variable to the end, however when checking the file there was no variable added.